# How do I properly use of a large JSON file

Tags: json, django, vuejs2, django-rest-framework

I have an 80mb JSON file that contains nearly all of the data my site will work with.

I'm unsure of how to proceed with this data. Is it possible (recommended?) to simply host the JSON file alongside my web app and access it whenever I need data?

I have experience with Django and have been planning on parsing the JSON into Django models and storing it within a database and using Django-Rest-Framework to communicate between the front-end (Vue.js2) and back-end, but I am curious what others out there recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's a good idea. First you have to create the models as per your requirements and then you have to load the data into the models/tables.
Django provides the fixures to load the initial into the models/tables. After you can write your API using django rest

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/initial-data/